# numpy array memory allocation

Tags: python, numpy

From what I've read about Numpy arrays, they're more memory efficient that standard Python lists. What confuses me is that when you create a numpy array, you have to pass in a python list. I assume this python list gets deconstructed, but to me, it seems like it defeats the purpose of having a memory efficient data structure if you have to create a larger inefficient structure to create the efficient one.

Does numpy.zeros get around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are [many ways to create a NumPy array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-creation.html). Passing a Python list to `np.array` or `np.asarray` is just one such way.

Another way is to use an iterator:

```
In [11]: np.fromiter(xrange(10), count=10, dtype='float')
Out[11]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])
```

In this case, there is no big temporary Python list involved. So instead of building a Python list, you could define a [generator function](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html#generators) which yields the items in the list. Then to create the array you'd pass the generator to `np.fromiter`. Since `np.fromiter` always creates a 1D array, to create higher dimensional arrays use `reshape` on the returned value.

There is also `np.fromfunction`, `np.frombuffer`, `np.fromfile`, `np.loadtxt`, `np.genfromtxt`,  `np.fromstring`, `np.zeros`, `np.empty` and `np.ones`. These all provide ways to create NumPy arrays without creating large temporary Python objects.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy in general is more efficient if you pre-allocate the size.  If you know you're going to be populating an MxN matrix...create it first then populate as opposed to using appends for example.

While the list does have to be created, a lot of the improvement in efficiency comes from acting on that structure.  Reading/writing/computations/etc.